# Set CFPreferences outside prefPane

Tags: objective-c, macos, cfpreferences

I'm trying to build an app that sets `CFPreferences` like so:

```
CFPreferencesSetValue((CFStringRef)@"AppleInterfaceStyle", NULL, kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

And then post a notification to let the system know it's been changed.

```
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification", NULL, NULL, YES);
    [defaults setObject:@"light" forKey:@"interfaceStyle"];
```

I've tried this in a normal Mac App and it doesn't work, but it works if I put it in a prefPane. Does anyone have any pointers?

This is specific to Yosemite and sets the theme to light (changes the menu bar and dock).

Comment: same here. I have been trying to do this in an app and the behaviour is very unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

wrapping the notification code inside dispatch_async worked for me. Not sure why though.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenteR(), 
   (CFStringRef)@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification", NULL, NULL, YES);
});
```